# Storing Unstructured Data in a Database

Tags: database, oracle, relational-database

I'm a little confused with a notion that relational databases don't store unstructured data well. Take for example a video file, which is unstructured. If you were to store that file in a NoSQL database you would probably just store in the file in the filesystem and the metadata in the database. The metadata can easily be stored in a relational database. So, what is about unstructured data that makes storing data in relational so difficult?

Comment: There are more efficient ways to store the data than an RDBMS.

Comment: Relational aspects (such as normalization and consistency) don't apply very well to data such as audio, video etc. On the other hand data management functionality (eg backup, recovery, security) can be useful. Identify your needs and find the most appropriate tool.

Comment: If a video file is unstructured, how does a decoder know how to render it?

Answer (score 0):

The relational model deals with associations among sets of values.  One could model a video as sets of frames but usually with video files we want to just stream the content, not describe or query it.  Relational databases are optimized to join, calculate, filter and sort large volumes of relatively simple rows.  None of that is required for video files, and encumbering a database server with streaming duties will detract from query processing too.  Note that it's not difficult at all to store BLOBs in most DBMSs, it's just inappropriate.  Use the right tool for the job.